# Again with the lotto program

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I had a problem before with a small lottery program that calucaltes all the combinations possible for 6/49 (in PHP).

This is my current problem. I use conditions so the numbers won't repeat, but in the next loop, when the first number is changed I have a repeating combination. Let me explain by an example:

I have this combination:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5 
1 2 3 6
...
1 2 4 3
1 2 4 5
1 2 4 6
```

So my lottery ticket `1 2 3 4` is the same as `1 2 4 3`.

Have any ideas how to solve it? I can't think of anything...

Here is the code (I only made it till 4/49 :D )

```
<?php

for ($i=1 ; $i<50 ; $i++)

{

    $a=$i;
    for ($j=1 ; $j<50 ; $j++)

    {

        if ($i!=$j)
        {
            $b=$j;



                for ($k=1 ; $k<50 ; $k++)

                {

                if ($k!=$j && $k!=$i)
                {
                    $c=$k;

                    for ($l=1 ; $l<50 ; $l++)

                    {

                        if ($l!=$i && $l!=$j && $l!=$k)
                        {
                            $d=$l;
                            echo "$a $b $c $d <br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

 ?>
 <br/><br/>
```

**Thank you !**

Update:

the code looks like this:

```
< ?php

  for($a=1; $a<50; $a++)

  {

     for($b=$a+1; $b<50; $b++)

  {

    for($c=$b+1; $c<50; $c++)

    {

        for($d=$c+1; $d<50; $d++)

        {

            for($e=$d+1; $e<50; $e++)

            {

                for($f=$e+1; $f<50; $f++)

                {

                   $t=$t+1;
                }
            }

        }
    }
  }
 }
 echo "$t";

 ?>
```

I do get the right answer but I allso get this error: "Undefined variable: t"
Any ideea why?

Comment: So essentially you're looking for all unique permutations of the numbers 1 - 49 in a 6-digit string?

Comment: I don't understand what your program is supposed to do, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No, he wants to *ignore* any permutation of a ticket number that was already printed. You could sort and store them in an array and then do a lookup if you already had that combination (`$a = array($a, $b, $c, $d); sort($a); $combinations[$a[0]][$a[1]][$a[2]][$a[3]] = true;`) but there is probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: Something like this http://pastebin.com/Th9mc9wz

Comment: Yes BenM.

@AndreKR:  thank you! i will try that

Comment: @Baba: sorry i don't understant youre link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get all combinations, you should initialize inner loop variable value to parent loop variable value + 1
Example for 4/49

```
for($a=1; $a<50-3; $a++)
    for($b=$a+1; $b<50-2; $b++)
        for($c=$b+1; $c<50-1; $c++)
            for($d=$c+1; $d<50; $d++)
                echo "$a $b $c $d<br>";
```

As a bonus, you don't need anymore to test if values are all different

Comment: Updated anwser: you can also avoid some loops by changing ending conditions

Comment: sorry.. i just did it. not working :)
for example, let's say in the middle of the program i will have this: 1 2 16 44 45 ; 1 2 16 44 46....1 2 16 44 49 ; 1 2 16 45 46 and so on.

Comment: i am a bit confuse my self... i don't even know if what i am saying is right or wrong... the ideea is that i added a $t=$t+1; after echo so i will know how many posibilitis i have and its not even close the the number people say on the internet is the posibilitis for wining the lottery.

Comment: my bad... when i runed it the first time it gave me around 19 milions, or 1.9 milions... i diden't read it carefully. the ideea is that the real probablity for 6/49 is around 13.9mil, so i know i was wrong.
i just runed it again now and it gave the the exact number 13983816 but with a error before the number: Undefined variable: t

still. the program works! :D

Comment: Let me get you  .. you want to get all posible combination of 6 digits form 1 , to 50 right ??

Comment: Ok let me give you a class .. try it out

Comment: I wanted to give you another solution .. since this works .. i guess you don't need it

Comment: But i can still give you if you want

Comment: sure. everything help. i am just trying to learn php and improve my way of seeing how to do this stuff... seeing the easeyest way, or any way possible for getting the right solutions. any right answer is helpfull for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You got the error undefined variable t as you were using directly $t=$t+1. But you have nowhere initialised $t. All other variables have been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR Combinatorics class does all this for you: http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics/docs/latest/Combinatorics/_Math_Combinatorics-1.0.0---Combinatorics.php.html